# react-scripts missing after install redux

Tags: reactjs, npm, redux, installation

i created react app according steps described here https://www.sitepoint.com/getting-started-react-beginners-guide/

```
npm i -g create-react-app
create-react-app myapp
yarn start
```

Everything worked ok, so i tried install redux as it described here
https://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html

```
npm install --save react-redux
```

I got this message

- react-redux@5.0.7
  added 3 packages, removed 1061 packages and updated 18 packages in 14.541s

and now when i try

```
yarn start
```

i get message

```
yarn run v1.3.2
$ react-scripts start
'react-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Whats wrong? I don't understand why is react-scripts not working. I thought that --save adds the third-party package to the package's dependencies and have nothing to do with other packages.
Iam thankfull for every advice what i did wrong and how to fix it.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `npm install --save react-redux` you should install `redux package` using  [**`yarn`**](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/usage).

`yarn add redux`

**issue :**

You are creating app using `yarn` package manager  and then adding new packages using `npm` causing to eject the packages installed using yarn.
Because of this `react-scripts` getting remove throwing the error.

Comment: Thank you for answer. 
I recreate missing  packages with npm install  it solved my problem.